# Traversing arrays

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

I have to create a program for my class that creates an array of election candidates and their number of votes, and traverses through the array to print each candidate with an overridden toString method, then print a table with each name, number of votes, and percent of total votes. My problem is that, instead of printing each of the 5 candidates, it prints the last candidate in the array 5 times. This is what I have:

```
public class Candidate {
    private String name;
    private int numVotes;

    public Candidate(String name, int numVotes){
        this.name = name;
        this.numVotes = numVotes;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getNumVotes(){
        return numVotes;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + " has " + numVotes + " votes.";
    }
}


public class TestCandidate {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Candidate[] election = new Candidate[5];

        election[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
        election[1] = new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000);
        election[2] = new Candidate("Michael Duffy", 6000);
        election[3] = new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500);
        election[4] = new Candidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800);

        printVotes(election);
        printResults(election);
    }

    public static void printVotes(Candidate[] list){
        for (Candidate candidate : list){
            System.out.println(candidate);
        }
    }

    public static int getTotal(Candidate[] list){
        int total = 0;
        for (Candidate candidate : list){
            total += candidate.getNumVotes();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void printResults(Candidate[] list){
        System.out.printf("%-10s %20s %20s", "Candidate", "Votes Received", "% of Total Votes");
        System.out.println();
        for (Candidate candidate : list){
            System.out.printf("%-10s %15s %15.2f", candidate.getName(), candidate.getNumVotes(), 100*(double)candidate.getNumVotes()/getTotal(list));
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("Total number of votes in election: " + getTotal(list));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for output something like:

```
John Smith has 5000 votes
Mary Miller has 4000 votes
...
Candidate   Votes Recieved    % of total votes
John Smith      5000                 25.91
Mary Miller     4000                 20.73
...
Total number of votes: 19300
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
Joe Ashtony has 1800 votes
Joe Ashtony has 1800 votes
...(x3)
Candidate   Votes Recieved    % of total votes
Joe Ashtony     1800                 20
Joe Ashtony     1800                 20
...(x3)
Total number of votes: 9000
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Try a clean build.

Comment: I'm betting the `Candidate` fields were initially `static`.

Comment: Your code looks fine - I think your IDE is messing with you.

Comment: System.out.print("Total number of votes in election: " + getTotal(list));

should probably be a println instead of print.

Also, try getting the total once, at the beginning of printResults, not once per candidate (you're not expecting it to change mid-iteration).

Comment: Same here, i'm getting expected results.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Which IDE are you using????

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea. I closed my IDE and reopened, works fine now, guess I just assumed it was my fault instead of technology lol. Thanks